# CMake include path of installed libraries

Tags: cmake

Suppose your project has multiple authors and depends on some libraries that must be installed on your system - you don't ship them with the project.

Some people have installed that libraries in `/usr`, `/usr/local/`, `/opt` or `/opt/local`.

What is the best practice to add them to the include path, without messing up `CMakeLists.txt` with all possible paths?

I am aware of `xxx_ROOT` variables like `BOOST_ROOT`, but not all library detections based on such a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teach your users / co-authors to use custom `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` which they can pass to their CMake call:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/local;/home/brandstifter/boost-1.70/ ..
```

For each find command, CMake will also search within the paths from `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. See its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).